# Using adafruit TLC5947 controlled by Arduino Mini

Tags: arduino, led, pwm

We're currently working on a little project but we've ran into some problems. We need a 0-10V PWM-signal to control some LEDs. As we need to individually control about 30 LEDs we decided to use two Adafruit 24-ch 12bit LED drivers controlled by an Arduino MINI.

We uploaded the next piece of code onto the Arduino but we have no voltage output on the adafruit board. We suspect the problem lies in the programming and we searched the web for solutions but we couldn't find any. Could someone help us?

```
#include "Adafruit_TLC5947.h"

#define NUM_TLC5974 1

#define data   4
#define clock   5
#define latch   6
#define oe  -1  // set to -1 to not use the enable pin (its optional)

Adafruit_TLC5947 tlc = Adafruit_TLC5947(NUM_TLC5974, clock, data, latch);

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);

  pinMode(4, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(5, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(6, OUTPUT);

  tlc.begin();

  tlc.setPWM(0, 2000);
  tlc.write();

  tlc.setPWM(1, 4096);
  tlc.write();

  tlc.setPWM(2, 1000);
  tlc.write();


}

void loop() {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get voltage on any channel of TLC5947 you have to add a pull up resistor on each channel. Outputs of TLC5947 are open collector thats why we connect cathode of LED to channels and anode to source.

Answer (score 0):

1. Did you attach resistor of value ~ 1k or 2k across IRef pin and
   Ground?
2. Put things in void loop(). Reason- You can't keep shift registers
   inside the TLC in floating state.

Since you are doing things in setup(), it will be written on uC pin only once. 
If you see the code of tlc.write(), the latch pin flips and the shift register again becomes empty. When the code reaches void loop(), its basically not doing anything, and your states defined in setup() are already gone with tlc.write() statement.

Comment: I disagree with at least point 2: tlc.setPWM issues an SPI command from the microcontroller to the TLC5947 chip which causes the TLC chip to generate the PWM signal, then you don't need the µC unless you want to change the PWM ratio or the channel.

Comment: We added a 1k resistor between the IRef pin of the Adafruit and the ground and now we do get a signal. However the signal we're getting is unusually small. The Adafruit is connected to a 5V source but the maximum signal (PWM 100%) we get is only a fraction of this. However that does bring me to the next question. As we want to go to voltages of up to 10V we tried to connect Adafruit to a 10V source. However the ON-LED on the Adafruit gives no sign of life. According to the datasheet this shouldn't be a problem.